# Connection refused on docker container

Tags: docker

I'm new to Docker and trying to make a demo Rails app. I made a dockerfile that looks like this:

```
FROM ruby:2.2
MAINTAINER marko@codeship.com

# Install apt based dependencies required to run Rails as 
# well as RubyGems. As the Ruby image itself is based on a 
# Debian image, we use apt-get to install those.
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
build-essential \
nodejs

    # Configure the main working directory. This is the base 
    # directory used in any further RUN, COPY, and ENTRYPOINT 
    # commands.
RUN mkdir -p /app
WORKDIR /app

    # Copy the Gemfile as well as the Gemfile.lock and install 
    # the RubyGems. This is a separate step so the dependencies 
    # will be cached unless changes to one of those two files 
    # are made.
COPY Gemfile Gemfile.lock ./
RUN gem install bundler && bundle install --jobs 20 --retry 5

# Copy the main application.
COPY . ./

# Expose port 8080 to the Docker host, so we can access it 
# from the outside.
EXPOSE 8080

# The main command to run when the container starts. Also 
# tell the Rails dev server to bind to all interfaces by 
# default.
CMD ["bundle", "exec", "rails", "server", "-b", "0.0.0.0", "-p", "8080"]
```

I then built it like so:

```
docker build -t demo .
```

And call a command to start the server which does start the server on port 8080:

```
Johns-MacBook-Pro:demo johnkealy$ docker run -it demo
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 4.2.5 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:8080
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
[2016-04-23 16:50:34] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
[2016-04-23 16:50:34] INFO  ruby 2.2.4 (2015-12-16) [x86_64-linux]
[2016-04-23 16:50:34] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=1 port=8080
```

I then try to find the correct IP to navigate to:

```
Johns-MacBook-Pro:demo johnkealy$ docker-machine ip default
192.168.99.100
```

I navigate to http://192.168.99.100:8080 and get the error This site can’t be reached 192.168.99.100 refused to connect.

What could I be doing wrong ?

Comment: try to run container with publish option. docker run -it demo --publish 8080:8080

Comment: thanks, @jozef, but I get "docker: Error response from daemon: Container command '--publish' not found or does not exist.."

Answer (score 85, accepted):

You need to publish the exposed ports by using the following options:

**-P (upper case) or --publish-all** that will tell Docker to use random ports from your host and map them to the exposed container's ports.

**-p (lower case) or --publish=[]** that will tell Docker to use ports you manually set and map them to the exposed container's ports.

The second option is preferred because you already know which ports are mapped. If you use the first option then you will need to call `docker inspect demo` and check which random ports are being used from your host at the **Ports** section.

Just run the following command:

```
docker run -it -p 8080:8080 demo
```

After that your url will work.

Comment: Yes, and remember to put `-p` **BEFORE** image name, not after.

Answer (score 42):

If you are using **Docker toolkit** on **window 10 home** you will need to access the webpage through docker-machine ip command. It is generally 192.168.99.100:

It is assumed that you are running with publish command like below.

```
docker run -it -p 8080:8080 demo
```

With Window 10 pro version you can access with localhost or corresponding loopback 127.0.0.1:8080 etc (Tomcat or whatever you wish). This is because you don't have a virtual box there and docker is running directly on Window Hyper V and loopback is directly accessible.

Verify the hosts file in window for any digression. It should have 
127.0.0.1 mapped to localhost

Comment: This worked for me! I'm running Docker via minikube and the IP was different. Got it by running `minikube ip`

Answer (score 16):

I had the same problem. I was using Docker Toolbox on Windows Home. 
Instead of `localhost` I had to use `http://192.168.99.100:8080/`.

You can get the correct IP address using the command:

```
docker-machine ip
```

The above command returned `192.168.99.100` for me.

Comment: in macOS when I run this I get ` command not found: docker-machine`

Comment: You are a genius. This is was worked for me. I am using Spring Boot + OpenLDAP, both of them in separate containers. By using localhost it didn't work. By replacing localhost with my actual ip did the trick.

Comment: Where did you get that `docker-machine` command from? It is not recognized neither on PowerShell nor WSL terminals.

Answer (score 8):

Command `EXPOSE` in your Dockerfile lets you bind container's port to some port on the host machine but it doesn't do anything else. 
When running container, to bind ports specify `-p` option.

So let's say you expose port 5000. After building the image when you run the container, run `docker run -p 5000:5000 name`. This binds container's port 5000 to your laptop/computers port 5000 and that portforwarding lets container to receive outside requests.

This should do it.

Answer (score 7):

In Docker Quickstart Terminal run following command:

```
$ docker-machine ip 192.168.99.100
```

Answer (score 3):

In Windows, you also normally need to run command line as administrator.

As standard-user:

```
docker build -t myimage -f Dockerfile .
Sending build context to Docker daemon  106.8MB
Step 1/1 : FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/runtime:3.0
Get https://mcr.microsoft.com/v2/: dial tcp: lookup mcr.microsoft.com on [::1]:53: read udp [::1]:45540->[::1]:53: read: 
>>>connection refused
```

But as an administrator.

```
docker build -t myimage -f Dockerfile .
Sending build context to Docker daemon  106.8MB
Step 1/1 : FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/runtime:3.0
3.0: Pulling from dotnet/core/runtime
68ced04f60ab: Pull complete                                                                                             e936bd534ffb: Pull complete                                                                                             caf64655bcbb: Pull complete                                                                                             d1927dbcbcab: Pull complete                                                                                             Digest: sha256:e0c67764f530a9cad29a09816614c0129af8fe3bd550eeb4e44cdaddf8f5aa40
Status: Downloaded newer image for mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/runtime:3.0
 ---> f059cd71a22a
Successfully built f059cd71a22a
Successfully tagged myimage:latest
```

Answer (score 3):

In some situations the internal process in the docker container is trying to bind to `localhost` (or `127.0.0.1` explicitly), but this can be a mistake. Consider trying binding to `0.0.0.0` instead. This has been a common problem for me in the past.

Comment: The Dockerfile in the question has a `rails server -b 0.0.0.0` option already.

Comment: this was the key to solving my issue with a gradio app running in Docker. Had to manually set it to 0.0.0.0 instead of default 127.0.0.1 and presto, it works. I have no clue why. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you use the `-p` flag before the image name like this:

```
docker run -p 8080:8080 demo
```

Answer (score 0):

If someone using docker compose make sure your containers are on the same network bridge like:

```
  container-1:
    networks:
     - app-network

  container-2:
    networks:
     - app-network
```

Answer (score 0):

### **The most default approach using python with docker in ubuntu**

in the root of the project run the command to create the *requirements.txt* file containing your virtual environament packages:

```
pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

create a new '*Dockerfile*' in the project root:

```
FROM python:3.10.12
WORKDIR /app
COPY requirements.txt ./
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt --quiet
COPY . .
EXPOSE 8000
CMD ["python", "manage.py", "runserver", "0.0.0.0:8000"]
```

execute bash command to **build** the docker image:

```
docker build -t my-app-img:0.1.0 .
```

execute bash command to **run** the image:

```
docker run --rm -d -p 8000:8000/tcp doospy-api:0.1.0
```

access it using the browser:

```
http://localhost:8000/
```

ubuntu 22.04,python 3.10.12, docker 24.0.7, venv

Answer (score 0):

### **The most simple approach using python with docker in ubuntu**

in the root of the project run the command to create the *requirements.txt* file containing your virtual environament packages:

```
pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

create a new '*Dockerfile*' in the project root:

```
FROM python:3.10.12
WORKDIR /app
COPY requirements.txt ./
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt --quiet
COPY . .
EXPOSE 8000
CMD ["python", "manage.py", "runserver", "0.0.0.0:8000"]
```

execute bash command to **build** the docker image:

```
docker build -t my-app-img:0.1.0 .
```

execute bash command to **run** the image:

```
docker run --rm -d -p 8000:8000/tcp doospy-api:0.1.0
```

access it using the browser:

```
http://localhost:8000/
```

ubuntu 22.04,python 3.10.12, docker 24.0.7, venv, django, rest_framework, restframework, image, container