# ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED on angular app hosted on nginx inside a docker container?

Tags: angular, docker, nginx

I am using Angular 9 and have an application that runs as expected.

e.g.

```
ng serve
```

I can then access it on:

```
http://localhost:4200/approval-edit/1573515
```

Now I would like to Dockerise it. I am following this tutorial:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J9uKG22lBwA

I have done the following:

```
ng build --prod
```

The `dist` directory is created.

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM nginx:1.17.1-alpine
COPY /dist/nexct-approval-ui /user/share/nginx/html
EXPOSE 4200
```

then I run:

```
docker build -t ng-nexct-approval-ui .
```

It looks like it builds correctly.

```
docker run -p 4200:4200 ng-nexct-approval-ui
```

When I try access `http://localhost:4200/approval-edit/1573515`, I get:

```
ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

**Questions**

1. Any ideas how I can get this working, so I can connect to
   `http://localhost:4200/approval-edit/1573515`?
2. Currently the docker container is just given a random name. How do I
   assign a name? (e.g. `ng-nexct-approval-ui-container`)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Connection refused on docker container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36813690/connection-refused-on-docker-container)

Comment: are you using docker for desktop or Docker Tollbox?

Comment: What kind of Docker do you have; more specifically, is it Docker Toolbox on Windows?

Comment: I change it to `docker run -p 4200:4200 --name ng-nexct-approval-ui-container ng-nexct-approval-ui-image`, and now I get `ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE`.

Comment: I am using Docker Desktop on MacOS

Comment: That seems to be a different question @Richard.

Comment: Ok try ```docker run -p 8080:4200 --name ng-nexct-approval-ui-container ng-nexct-approval-ui``` and go to ```http://localhost:8080```

Comment: It would really help if you explained what our changing and why @DashrathMundkar

Comment: Well this ```docker run -p 8080:4200 --name ng-nexct-approval-ui-container ng-nexct-approval-ui ``` command maps the container port to localhost port. did this worked for you?

Comment: I have changed it to `-p 8080:4200`, and now I get `ERR_SOCKET_NOT_CONNECTED`

Comment: Should I remove `EXPOSE 4200` from the Dockerfile?

Comment: The question is where your application get exposed on which port?

Comment: I have always run it on the angular default of 4200.  ie. if I don't access it via docker and just use `ng serve`, it works on port 4200.

Comment: try running on different port like ```docker run -p 8081:4200 --name ng-nexct-approval-ui-container ng-nexct-approval-ui ``` and go to ```localhost:8081```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218275/discussion-between-dashrath-mundkar-and-richard).

Comment: Can you try this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62913449/6332074)?

Comment: The docker is running nginx which is not on port 4200

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answer to your question is. Nginx expose port on 8080 and Dockerfile has port 4200 to solve problem map the port to localhost port.

```
docker run -p 4200:8080 --name ng-nexct-approval-ui-container ng-nexct-approval-ui
```

Comment: Unfortunately that foes not work. `http://localhost:8080/` returns `ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE` and `http://localhost:4200/` returns `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`.

Comment: I am currently looking at the following, which is a different approach by importing node.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=etA5xiX5TCA

Comment: @Richard try now. I have updated my answer. The problem is nginx does not expose on 4200 rather it expose it on 8080, initially I thought it was your application port, so either you should update the dockerfile with 8080 or run the docker run command as I have updated

Comment: Thanks.  I can now access nginx

Answer (score 0):

**1st question:**

When you run your Angular application in the dev server, it is hosted on port `4200`. Now you are using an nginx container, which does not run on port `4200`, but port `80`.

You should try to run the container with `docker run -p 4200:80 ng-nexct-approval-ui` instead.

You could also update the `EXPOSE` section of Dockerfile to port `80`. It doesn't change the functionality however, since it merely serves as documentation.

> The EXPOSE instruction does not actually publish the port. It functions as a type of documentation between the person who builds the image and the person who runs the container, about which ports are intended to be published. To actually publish the port when running the container, use the -p flag on docker run to publish and map one or more ports, or the -P flag to publish all exposed ports and map them to high-order ports.

[Source](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#expose)

**2nd question:**

You can assign a name to your docker container by using the `--name` option, so in this case `docker run --name <your name here> ng-nexct-approval-ui`.